# Why does open CyUSB device in Python segfault when the same code runs fine in VC++?

Tags: python, c++

I wrote a python wrapper around CyAPI.lib and build the wrapper project using VC++. (I suspect this is related to my problem.) I am using Cypress Fx3 streamer example device as well as Cypress bootloader device.

The CCyUSBDevice::Open(index) crashes Python (no exception or traceback). But the  CCyUSBDevice::Open(index) function works fine if I run it on Visual Studio 2008 with the same device, same driver on the same computer.

The calling code is really simple. Please take a look at the following codes.
In Python:

```
>>>from wrapprj import *
>>>try:
...   openDevice()   ###exception happens here and quit python,no way to get following exception No. and string.
...except Exception as e:
...   print "exception is {0}:{1}".format(e.errno,e.strerror)
```

In wrap file:

```
static PyObject *
do_openDevice(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
{
    bool ret;
    ret = call_openCyUSBDevice();
    return Py_BuildValue("O", ret?Py_True: Py_False);
}

PyMethodDef methods[] = {
    {"openDevice", do_openCyUSBDevice, METH_VARARGS,
        "open CyUSB Device"},        
    {NULL, NULL},
};
```

In CPP file:

```
extern "C" bool
call_openCyUSBDevice(void)
{
    devHandler = new CCyUSBDevice(NULL,CyUSBDevice_GUID,False);//don't try to open the device here. Otherwise exception happens here.

    if (NULL == devHandler)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return devHandler->Open(0); // exception happens. But if I add some printing before this line, it CAN OPEN correctly. STRANGE!
}
```

In Cyapi.h, CCyUSBDevice::Open() is defined like this:

```
class CCyUSBDevice
{
public:

  CCyUSBDevice(HANDLE hnd = NULL, GUID guid = CYUSBDRV_GUID, BOOL bOpen = true);
  ~CCyUSBDevice(void);
  .
  .
  bool                  Open(UCHAR dev);
  .
  .
}
```

In Visual Studio C++ 2008, I run the code like this and works fine:

```
    public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        CCyUSBDevice *USBDevice;
    public: 
        Form1(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            USBDevice = new CCyUSBDevice(NULL,CyUSBDevice_GUID,False);
            USBDevice->Open(0);
        }
    .
    .
    }
```

Why VC++ can open device correctly but my python wrapper can not when they both call the same underlying code?